# SQLAlchemy DB upgrade and MySQL SSH

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Flask application that I need to connect to a distant MysqlDB using a SSHTunnel like this in my config.py file I init in my **init**.py file:

```
sshtunnel.SSH_TIMEOUT = 5.0
sshtunnel.TUNNEL_TIMEOUT = 5.0

server =  sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('ssh.pythonanywhere.com', 22),
    ssh_password="mypassword",
    ssh_username="myusername",
    remote_bind_address=(myname.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com', 3306))
server.start()

engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://mynameb:dbpassword@127.0.0.1:%s/dbname' % server.local_bind_port)
```

The connection seems to be working but I can't upgrade my DB from my migrations (flask db upgrade) since I'm not using SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI to connect to my DB. Is there still a way to make the db upgrade working with a ssh connection to the DB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alembic doesn't have to connect to the database using the database URI to run upgrades. In your `alembic\env.py` file there will be a function like this:

```
def run_migrations_online():
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """
    connectable = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section),
        prefix='sqlalchemy.',
        poolclass=pool.NullPool)

    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection,
            target_metadata=target_metadata
        )

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()
```

All that matters is that that the variable `connectable` is an `engine` instance when alembic calls `connect()` on it.

Therefore you could do something like this (this isn't tested but I do something similar myself):

```
def run_migrations_online():
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """

    sshtunnel.SSH_TIMEOUT = 5.0
    sshtunnel.TUNNEL_TIMEOUT = 5.0

    server =  sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
        ('ssh.pythonanywhere.com', 22),
        ssh_password="mypassword",
        ssh_username="myusername",
        remote_bind_address=\
            (myname.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com', 3306))
    server.start()

    connectable = create_engine(
        'mysql+mysqldb://mynameb:dbpassword@127.0.0.1:%s/dbname' % 
        server.local_bind_port
    )

    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection,
            target_metadata=target_metadata
        )

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()
```

Ideally you'd put all of your connection logic somewhere it can be accessed both from the `alembic/env.py` and in your project so you only have it defined once and then you could just import the `engine` directly into `env.py`, but you get the idea.